# How to open pretrained models in python

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, spss, pre-trained-model

Hi I'm trying to load some pretrained models from `.sav` files and so far nothing is working. The models were originally made in pytorch and when I open the raw file in vs-code I can see that all the appropiate information was stored correctly.

I've tried the following libraries:

`sklearn.externals.joblib`

`pickle`

`scipy.io`

`pyreadstat`

Each library either gave me an error (such as `wrong timestamp` or `signature mismatch`) or just return an `int` instead of a python object.

The models can be downloaded from [this link](http://bergerlab-downloads.csail.mit.edu/bepler-protein-sequence-embeddings-from-structure-iclr2019/pretrained_models.tar.gz).

Comment: if the files were saved using `torch.save` then you should try `torch.load` to load them

Comment: @CertainlyNotAdrian I think I answered your question, and even tested the solution. Do you mind marking my answer accepted?  If not, then please point out in a comment where you think my answer is lacking, so I can address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use PyTorch to load the models. On top of this, you also need the original model definition, so you need to need the clone the authors repository. In your example this repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/tbepler/protein-sequence-embedding-iclr2019.git
```

Then you can open the model with `torch.load()`. Note that you need the model definition on your path (you can simply launch python from the repo directory).

Then it's straightforward to open a file:

```
import torch
model = torch.load('<downloaded models>/<model name>.sav')
print(model)
```

The last line prints the model definition. For example,  `me_L1_100d_lstm3x512_lm_i512_mb64_tau0.5_p0.05_epoch100.sav` produced the following output:

```
OrdinalRegression(
  (embedding): StackedRNN(
    (embed): LMEmbed(
      (lm): BiLM(
        (embed): Embedding(22, 21, padding_idx=21)
        (dropout): Dropout(p=0)
        (rnn): ModuleList(
          (0): LSTM(21, 1024, batch_first=True)
          (1): LSTM(1024, 1024, batch_first=True)
        )
        (linear): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=21, bias=True)
      )
      (embed): Embedding(21, 512, padding_idx=20)
      (proj): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=512, bias=True)
      (transform): ReLU()
    )
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0)
    (rnn): LSTM(512, 512, num_layers=3, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
    (proj): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=100, bias=True)
  )
  (compare): L1()
)
```